# How to create a custom Dataset for YOLO v3 by LabelImg

Tags: opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

I have used LabelImg Save as YOLO option to save my label in the form of .txt with the format like

```
6 0.333984 0.585938 0.199219 0.160156
```

But I want it to be in this format

```
path/to/img1.jpg 50,100,150,200,0 30,50,200,120,3
path/to/img2.jpg 120,300,250,600,2
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

YOLO uses **relative** values rather than raw pixel values. In other words, the format is:

center-x center-y width height

Where center-x is the **percentage** of the width. In other words, if the image is 800px wide, and the center-x is at 400px, the center-x would be written as `0.5`.

So your Labellmg values are already correct for training YOLO. Also, in YOLO v3 you do actually need them all to be separate .txt files, rather than in one big long file. So you're already good to go.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what is center-x and center-y?

Answer (score 0):

Disagree with the above answer. Not all implementations require percentage of width, center or height and the implementations of Yolo I used require a single train.txt file. A specific one for example https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3 requires exact format mentioned in the question but the 4 numbers are coordinates top right x, top right y, bottom right x, bottom right y followed by class number. Nevertheless you can use those text files and merge them together in a csv including the name of the image in a column as well. This can be done using glob or pandas library. You can do the width, height calculations in the csv for the whole column at once. Then add the path to the complete column at once and convert it into a text file and it will be ready for input.